# PHP week and day from start date

Tags: php

I have a subscription date for a user. eg 2019-07-04.

Depending on the week (1,2,3,4) or day(1-7) I need to determine which week or day it is relative to the starting date.

So 2019-07-04 would be Week1, Day1
2019-07-05 would be Week1, Day2 etc

The cycle must repeat so if we reach week4, day7, the next day must be week1, day1 again

The weeks can be any amount and the days <= 7

Any ideas? Please note Carbon is not an option

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show us what you have already tried and what errors you are getting. Also please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with dates there can be a lot of variables that can be tedious.

But if you're just looking to calculate the weeks and days from a certain point, try this out:

```
$date1 = "2019-07-04";
$date2 = "2019-10-05";

$temp = dateDifference($date1, $date2);

$temp = $temp % 35;

echo "Week" . floor($temp/7) . " Day". $temp % 7;

function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 ) {

    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format('%R%a days');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. you will get week number.

```
<?php 
        $date = '2019-07-04'; //please define your date here 

        $ts = strtotime($date);
        $start = (date('w', $ts) == 1) ? $ts : strtotime('last monday', $ts);
        $startDate = date('Y-m-d', $start);
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next sunday', $start));

        $month = date('m', strtotime($startDate));
        $year = date('Y', strtotime($startDate));


        $first_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first monday of $year-$month"));
        $last_date = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($first_date));
        $first_week = date("W", strtotime($first_date));
        $last_week = date("W", strtotime($last_date));
        $monthlyWeekCount = 1;

        if ($month == 12) {

            $ddate = "$year-12-31";
            $date = new DateTime($ddate);
            $Dweek = $date->format("W");
            if ($Dweek == 1) {
                $last_week = date('W', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 28, $year));
                $last_week = $last_week + 1;
            }
        }
        $monthlyWeekCount = 1;
        for ($i = $first_week; $i <= $last_week; $i++) {

            $dto = new DateTime();
            $dto->setISODate($year, $i);
            $monthData['start_date'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
            $dto->modify('+6 days');
            $monthData['end_date'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');

            $MonthlyWeekNumber = '';

            if ($monthData['start_date'] == $startDate && $monthData['end_date'] == $endDate) {
                $MonthlyWeekNumber = $monthlyWeekCount;
                break;
            }
            $monthlyWeekCount++;
        }

        $details['startDate'] = $startDate;
        $details['endDate'] = $endDate;
        $details['week_number'] = $MonthlyWeekNumber;
        $details['month'] = $month;

    /***Output--***/
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($details);
    die;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-06-14' ); //please insert your date here

    $dateDiff = $date->diff( new DateTime() )->format('%a');
    if ( $dateDiff > 0 ) {
        $subscriptionCount = intval( intval( $dateDiff ) / ( 7 * 4 ) );
        $currentWeekCount = intval( $dateDiff / 7 ) % 4;
        $currentDayCount = $dateDiff % 7 + 1;
    } else {
        echo 'invalid day';
    }

    echo $subscriptionCount.' times renew'.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'last renew after '.$currentWeekCount.' weeks '.$currentDayCount.' days'.PHP_EOL;
```